# Configuring sharepoint 2007 (wss) for sending and receiving mail

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am using Sharepoint 2007 (WSS) in my organisazation. I have done it's setup part. But i am unable to configure it for sending and receiving mail.

Problem in my case is that my Exchange Server and Sharepoint is configured on same machine so when try to configure SMTP it shows error.And giving suggestion to use POP3 .

Can anyone help me out to configuring sharepoint in above scenario.

Regards,

Preeti